# Running my rails application on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger

This is my first experience deploying a rails app to a server. It works perfectly fine locally, but when I am trying to move it to the server for production, it doesn't show up. All I get is my project folder's images shown. Do I need to make any changes?

Following are the changes I have already done -
database.yml -> production
changed the environment

I have used phusion passenger and apache for this purpose. Anyone who has faced a similar situation, please help me out. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Also the server I am trying to run on has projects running on ruby 1.8.7; there were 2 instances when my project was using another project's gemsets. So had to use .rvmrc (which i know is deprecated as of now) to point it to the right gemset that my app should be using.

Configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName cloudapp.net
  DocumentRoot /var/www/test1/public
  <Directory /var/www/test1/public>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Passenger Configuration:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.20/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/passenger-4.0.20
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p448/ruby
```

Comment: do you know `.ruby-version`, `.ruby-gemset` are the replacement for `.rvmrc`? [read this](http://rvm.io/workflow/projects#project-file-ruby-version)

Comment: I have removed rvmrc for now and used the gemset for project but the problem still persists , i don't have any idea what else i need to do more to run it on production .

Comment: Firstly, try running the application in production mode on your remote server using rails built in `WEBrick` server using `rails server -e production -p 80`. Once you get `WEBrick` to boot up without errors, switch to apache/passenger. You should also post more descriptive error messages and relevant content from your config files here to get help.

Comment: I do it on localhost:3000 and it works fine . adding -p 80 throws error . Error - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': app/models/user.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)

Comment: Post your apache virtual host configuration and your passenger configuration lines

Comment: Did it , have a look .

Comment: and passenger configuration?

Comment: Maybe that is where i am going wrong , passenger configuration shows it's using 1.9.3-p225 and i want to use 1.9.3-p448 . Is that a problem ?

Comment: posting an answer as the comment thread is getting too long. You should really post all the information you have so that people can understand your **specific** problem and guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you followed every steps?

```
cap deploy:setup

cap deploy:cold
```

Have you created symlinks? I will post a working demo of my file here..

My deploy.rb

```
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'
require "bundler/capistrano"
require "rvm/capistrano"

set :user, 'ubuntu'
set :application, "yourapp"
set :use_sudo, true

$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
set :rvm_path,          "/home/ubuntu/.rvm"
set :rvm_bin_path,      "#{rvm_path}/bin"
set :rvm_lib_path,      "#{rvm_path}/lib"


set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-1.9.3-p448'
set :rvm_type, :system

set :default_environment, {
  'PATH' => "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin:$PATH",
  'RUBY_VERSION' => 'ruby-1.9.3-p448',
  'GEM_HOME'     => "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448",
  'GEM_PATH'     => "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global",
  'BUNDLE_PATH'  => "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global"  # If you are using bundler.
}


set :scm, 'git'
# # repository to be set for gitlab
set :repository, "git@github.com:ur-repo.git"


# set :branch, "staging"


set :git_shallow_clone, 1
set :deloy_via, :remote_cache
set :keep_releases, 3
set :scm_verbose, true


set :stages, ["staging", "production"]
set :default_stage, "staging"

set :migrate_target, :latest



default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = false
ssh_options[:keys] = ["yourfile.pem"]



after "deploy:create_symlink", "deploy:bundle_install"

namespace :bundler do
  task :create_symlink, roles: :app do
    shared_dir = File.join(shared_path, 'bundle')
    release_dir = File.join(current_release, '.bundle')
    run("mkdir -p #{shared_dir} && ln -s #{shared_dir} #{release_dir}")
  end

  task :bundle_new_release, roles: :app do
    bundler.create_symlink
    run "cd #{release_path} && source $HOME/.bash_profile && bundle install"
  end
end

after 'deploy:finalize_update', 'bundler:bundle_new_release'
after 'deploy:bundle_install', 'deploy:precompile_application'
after 'deploy:restart', 'deploy:cleanup'
```

And my staging.rb

```
set :domain, "yourdomain"


set :rails_env, "staging"

# roles (servers)
role :web, domain
role :app, domain
role :db,  domain, :primary => true


set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{application}"



namespace :deploy do

  desc "Copy config files"
  after "deploy:update_code" do
    run "export RAILS_ENV=staging"
    run "cp #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/"
    run "cp #{shared_path}/config/environments/staging.rb #{release_path}/config/environments/"
    run "mkdir -p #{release_path}/public/images/ProfilePics"    
    sudo "chmod -R 0777 #{release_path}/tmp/"
    sudo "chmod -R 0777 #{release_path}/log/"
  end

  task :restart, roles: :app, except: { no_release: true } do
    run "touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end

  desc 'run bundle install'
  task :bundle_install, roles: :app do
    run "cd #{current_path} && bundle install --deployment --path #{shared_path}/bundle"
  end  

  desc "Reset the database"
  task :reset do
    # on_rollback { deploy.db.restore }
    run "cd #{current_path}; bundle exec rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=staging"
  end

  desc "Migrate the database"
  task :migrate do
    # on_rollback { deploy.db.restore }
    run "cd #{current_path}; bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=staging"
  end

  task :seed do
    run "cd #{current_path}; bundle exec rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=staging"
  end


  task :precompile_application do
    run "cd #{current_path}; bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=staging"
  end

end
```

Comment: Will try this once i have my hands on the office machine . Looks good to me though , should do the needful :)

Comment: Yeah! Let me know if youre stuck somewhere! :)

Comment: The ones(staging.rb & deploy.rb) installed directly by doing 'cap install' have a different format then what you have mentioned . Should i clear all of it out and paste yours there ?

Comment: Also i had installed these 2 gems - rvmsudo gem install passenger & rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module

Comment: Yes I think you should back yours up and try these.. Also, you should not use rvmsudo why not rvm instead.. the default ones are just for the sake of familiarity. Is apache working fine?

Comment: Apache is working fine as other projects are running on it too so no issues there .

Comment: Great.. How about the passenger config? Workin fine?

Comment: Yea , passenger is enabled is wat the message shows . And restarted the server after dat too . Sorry for being such a pain ..... but this problem doesn't seem to go away .

Comment: I would rather suggest that you should create a gemset of your own on server by rvm gemset create (http://rvm.io/gemsets/creating) and later give that path in your capistrano configuration. That would be a better way if you have multiple apps on your server

Comment: Like,
'PATH' => "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@your_new_gemset/bin:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin:$PATH",
  'RUBY_VERSION' => 'ruby-1.9.3-p448',
  'GEM_HOME'     => "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@your_new_gemset",
  'GEM_PATH'     => "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@your_new_gemset:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global",
  'BUNDLE_PATH'  => "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@your_new_gemset:/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global"  # If you are using bundler.


Sorry for the mess! Was In hurry!

Comment: I have switched to a new server , everything is installed here . The old server had rvm version issues and hence gemsets were clashing . I am trying all the suggestions now on the fresh installation as we speak .

Comment: Okay! Better way! Post if you have any thorns while movin ahead!

Comment: Nope it worked perfectly on the new one . Although the app is throwing a different refinery error now . But glad that it has showed up on the web page as of now :) Any experience wid refinery ?

Comment: Nope! Just saw it.. Failing build on git! ;) Maybe you could post the error. Thanks for the voteup!

Comment: Ah , no problem on that . You went out of your way to help me out , and those recipes were exactly what solved my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Your passenger configuration looks alright.

Your `PassengerDefaultRuby` is pointing to `1.9.3-p448`. What makes you believe it is using `1.9.3-p225`?

Since you are using `RVM`, run these commands to find the correct ruby path for your passenger

```
rvm use 1.9.3
passenger-config --ruby-command
```

Then use the output of the command and add this line in your `VirtualHost` block  to force your application to use a specific version of ruby.

```
PassengerRuby /path/to/ruby/1.9.3/
```

Note: This is in addition to `PassengerDefaultRuby` you have already defined. [(See Documentation for PassengerRuby)](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerRuby)

Run this command to check folder permissions

```
passenger-config --root
```

Activate [Logging and Debugging](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_logging_and_debugging_options) to see what exactly passenger is doing

Comment: I edited and posted the new passenger config , earlier it was showing 1.9.3-p125 . Also i am using rvm (and depend heavily on it) for all the projects .