# Nginx + Passenger + Rails Server Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, passenger, ubuntu-14.04

When i try to go to my server i get the following error

[image]

```
App 13379 stdout:
App 13379 stdout:
[ 2015-02-02 05:28:59.1782 13226/7fb5d9699700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:287 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/www/noise: An error occured while starting up the pr$
  Error ID: b4c47933
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-U83DbV.html
  Message from application: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:263:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:366:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:261:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'


[ 2015-02-02 05:28:59.1863 13226/7fb5d7363700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:2306 ]: [Client 19] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier$
```

**NginX Config Content**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # nginx-naxsi config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
        ##

        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

        ##
        # Phusion Passenger config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
        ##

        #Web SERVER
        server {
            server_name 104.236.218.36;
            listen 80;
            root /var/www/noise/public;
            passenger_enabled on;
        }

        # API SERVER
        server {
            server_name 104.236.218.36;
            listen 3333;
            root /var/www/noise-api/public;
            passenger_enabled on;
        }

        #passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
        #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
        passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.58;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/wrappers/ruby;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


# mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
# }
```

**Update**

After changing the following

```
passenger_root /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/passenger-4.0.58;
        passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/wrappers/ruby;
```

Am getting the following Error Log

```
2015/02/02 06:16:06 [error] 13528#0: *3 directory index of "/var/www/noise/public/" is forbidden, client: 122.178.204.27, server: 104.236.218.36, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", ho$
```

Comment: Can you post the nginx.conf file contents ?

Comment: @CaffeineCoder have updated it :D

Comment: What's the output of this command - gem install bundler

Comment: @CaffeineCoder Successfully installed bundler-1.7.12
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.7.12
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.7.12
Done installing documentation for bundler after 2 seconds
1 gem installed

Comment: Does it still show the error in the process you followed earlier ?

Comment: Have you used capistrano in the application ?

Comment: @CaffeineCoder am getting the following error now 2015/02/02 06:16:06 [error] 13528#0: *3 directory index of "/var/www/noise/public/" is forbidden, client: 122.178.204.27, server: 104.236.218.36, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", ho$

Comment: @CaffeineCoder nope. right now doing it manually.

Comment: Please use capistrano , it's more helpful in building symlinks than doing it manually .

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure your Nginx config's passenger_ruby is your Rails App's ruby version.

if you install for passenger's way and use RVM, it will be usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/

```
    passenger_root /your-ruby-version/gems/passenger-4.0.50;
    passenger_ruby /your-ruby-version/wrappers/ruby;
```

hope this information will help :)

Comment: I am sorry i did not understand. I have used RVM to install Ruby on the server.

Comment: present configuration 
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
        passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

Comment: I changed it and i am getting the following error now 2015/02/02 06:16:06 [error] 13528#0: *3 directory index of "/var/www/noise/public/" is forbidden, client: 122.178.204.27, server: 104.236.218.36, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", ho$

Comment: try chmod your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

From what i am guessing , nginx isn't able to connect to your application . Lets do so using [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano)

Install the gem , and then run - bundle exec cap install

Based on an earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288853/running-my-rails-application-on-server) i had asked , copy over the contents from the deploy and staging files in your folder . Set the addresses accordingly and try it out . Do let me if i can help further .